# Make dropdownlist mandatory for continuing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, if-statement, razor

I have a form for users to fill out  various inputs and dropdowns.
One of the dropdowns has a yes or no boolean as the options.
I'm trying to write an if statement to prevent users from leaving it blank.

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="input-group ">
            <span class="input-group-addon white">Yes or No</span>
            <select class="form-control gray" id="returnSelect">
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                <option value="0">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried the following:

```
        if (data.yesOrNo == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Please select 'Yes' or 'No' for Multiple Returns");
        }
```

and

```
        if (data.yesOrNo != true && data.yesOrNo != false)
        {
            return BadRequest("Please select 'Yes' or 'No' for Multiple Returns");
        }
```

A bit primitive, but neither work.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you try with  if(returnSelect.SelectedIndex < 0)

Comment: Can you share the value of `data.yesOrNo` and share the type of `data.yesOrNo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have had a typo or something because the following worked after I cleaned up some of the code.

```
if (data.yesOrNo == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Please select 'Yes' or 'No' for Multiple Returns");
    }
```